# two right navigationBar button showing offset problem

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

create two right bar button, code like:

```
UIView *settingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 30)];
UIView *messageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *bar1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingView];
UIBarButtonItem *bar2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:messageView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[bar1,bar2];
```

most device show normal ,but very little iphoneXS Max show problem

**normal Image:**
[image]

**problem Image:**
[image]

how to fix it, help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the array of **UIBarButtonItem** to **rightBarButtonsItems** property of *navigationItem*.

Just ***initalize*** the UIBarButtonItem with **Image** method instead of **customView**. You will don't need to even assign the frame and all, Just like below.

```
let barButtonItemOne = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .plain, target: self, action: "selectorMethodGoesHere")
let barButtonItemTwo = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .plain, target: self, action: "selectorMethodGoesHere")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [barButtonItemOne, barButtonItemTwo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "button1Image"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(button1Tapped))
let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "button2Image"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(button2Tapped))
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([button1,button2], animated: true)
```